# ThreeJS reflection and refraction at the same time

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm trying to make a glass object. As you probably know, glass reflects, and is transparent at the same time.

When making a cubeTexture in ThreeJS, you have to choose between `CubeReflectionMapping` or `CubeRefractionMapping`. But what if I want to use both?

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, materials );`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/utils/SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject)

Comment: This is not the solution. If I assign 2 materials, of which 1 is not transparent, the object will still not be transparent and reflective at the same time. :( thanks for your answer tho!